# What was the thing revealed at the end of the Thor movie?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, thor-marvel, thor-2011

At the end of the Thor movie, after the credits there is a scene that shows Nick Fury and the professor from the movie discussing something in an underground base. It is shown that

> There is a blue cube that has almost unlimited power if it's able to be tapped. Also, Loki shows up and has the professor agree to look into it.

What is this thing that is revealed?

Comment: All of this stuff is building up to the Avengers movie. Which will either be absolutely amazing or the biggest Marvel blunder to date. There is no middle ground. But judging by the general high quality of the source series: Iron Man, Thor, Captain America, kinda Hulk, and possibly others in cameo: X-men, Fantastic Four, Spiderman; I have high hopes.

Comment: The cube was seen in the Captain America movie.

Comment: Was this the same, or same thing as, the powerful cube which the Frost Giants broke into Asgard to try to steal in the beginning of `THOR`?

Comment: @eidylon Nope, the thing the Frost Giants were after was the [Casket of Ancient Winters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casket_of_Ancient_Winters#CoAW).  At the time, the Cosmic Cube was sitting on Earth either in SHIELD's possession, or on the bottom of the ocean.

Comment: @DampeS8N Alas, no X-Men (Fox), Fantastic Four (also Fox), or Spiderman (Sony) as Marvel licensed those movies to other studios, so none of them are part of this new shared universe of movies.

Comment: @Keen: [this image expresses my feelings](http://9.media.dorkly.cvcdn.com/28/76/c94918cd1a4b2275c746cb475af9386b.jpg)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I believe that was a [Cosmic Cube](http://marvel.wikia.com/Cosmic_Cube), known in the Marvel Cinematic Universe as a Tesseract.  They are objects of immense power, able to turn thought into reality.

Possessing a Cube makes someone a veritable god.

Loki getting his grubby hands on one wouldn't be good for anyone (except maybe Loki).

It seems, after watching *Avengers* and the rest of the current MCU, that there is only one Tesseract, as opposed to there being multiple Cosmic Cubes in 616 Marvel (main comics universe).  The Tesseract, as well as the Aether from *Thor: The Dark World*, is also one of the Infinity Stones/Gems in the MCU.

Comment: Also remember that in the retcon for the Beyonder, it's been determined that the Beyonder was an *incomplete* Cosmic Cube, and [look at what he did](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beyonder#Powers_and_abilities).

Comment: Hey Jeff, can you edit this to incorporate the info from Thor 2? We now know the Tesseract to be the Space Infinity Stone.

Comment: @Keen: How, exactly, do we know that?  I watched it recently and didn't pick up on that.

Comment: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/43755/1027

Comment: @Keen: Well, there you go then.  Maybe I made the unforgivable error of now watching all the way through the credits, because I hadn't seen that scene before.

Comment: There are people who don't sit through all the credits in Marvel movies?! *gasp*

Comment: @phantom42 *faints*

Answer (score 6):

As Jeff says, it's the Cosmic Cube, a Marvel [McGuffin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacGuffin) designed to do whatever is needed by the plot, from making evil people able to shoot lasers from their eyes to birthing godlike entities.

In the Movie continuity, the Cosmic Cube, also known as the Tesseract,

> was a relic left behind by Odin after the Frost Giant wars, and was used by the Red Skull to power his Death Rays and Flying Bombs. At the end he ended up holding it in his bare hands and weird stuff happened, apparently tearing the Red Skull to pieces.

Comment: Red Skull ended up 'walking with the gods' like he always viewed himself doing.  This meant he got transported to another of the 9 realms by the cube.  If you've seen Thor, the Bifrost Bridge special effects they used when Red Skull vanished will be familiar.

Comment: The intriguing thing is that, if true, we haven't seen *where* the Red Skull ended up.