# Infinity Stones in the Marvel Cinematic Universe

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, thor-marvel, thor-the-dark-world, infinity-stones

In the mid-credits scene of *Thor: The Dark World*,

> Sif and Volstagg give The Collector an Infinity Stone.

They comment on the Tesseract as though it is an Infinity Stone as well.  Since they didn't just get the Tesseract, but *did* have the opportunity to recently procure

> the Aether

does this mean that it was the second Infinity Stone?  Or was something else in the film the second Infinity Stone?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**The Aether the Reality Stone.**

There have been lots of interviews with Marvel execs confirming it’s an Infinity Stone, and the way it’s shown in *Age of Ultron* confirms this in-universe.

An interview with [Kevin Feige](http://www.craveonline.co.uk/entertainment/film/interviews/852437-exclusive-interview-kevin-feige-on-the-infinity-stones-civil-war-and-more-marvel-studios/3) states that, as of *Age of Ultron*, only the Time and Soul Stones are unaccounted for, and so by a process of elimination, we may deduce that the Aether is Reality.

Comment: I expect the Aether to be the red gem (i.e. Power) too.  It explains how powerful its wielder became.

Comment: Just got back from a rewatch.  In the scene where Odin explains to Jane and Thor the history of the Aether, he refers to 'relics' that predate the universe.  He says they're usually in the form of stones.  One of them is the Aether....

Comment: In the spoiler version of the Empire podcast with Feige, Hiddleston et al., Feige confirms this again.

Comment: @Keen If that's the case, why isn't Tesseract purple?

Comment: Age of Ultron has shown them all as stones.

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely remade version of the Infinity Gems for the movies. There is only one continual error there, which is also debated in video dedicated to Thor Dark World mid-credit scene on IGN website. In Thor, you can clearly see, that the Infinity gauntlet (possibly with the infinity gems) is stored in Odin's Vault. We can only speculate, that the gauntlet is empty and it will be stolen by Thanos and the stones will be inserted into it in future films or it is just a easter-egg in the movie putted here for the audience with no effect on the story the same way as the Dr. Henry McCoy easter-egg in X-men 2 (he appeared on  a TV screen during the scene where Mystique were seducing a prison guard working in Magneto's cell).

Answer (score -1):

Comics and movies may not go the same way.
Even thought in the comics, there are 6 gems including power, space, mind, reality, time and soul, in the movies, Tesseract, Aether and the others do not have to completely be the same ability, color and shape as that gems.

Comment: Atleast they kept the same colour so far.

Answer (score -2):

I agree that it might be a continuity error. In the first Thor movie, you can clearly see the "Infinity Gauntlet" in a glass case (in Odin's vault) and it already contained colored gems or stones.
[See here: http://marvel-movies.wikia.com/wiki/Infinity_Gauntlet ]
However, they can always "course correct" and say those are just regular jewels and someone replaces them with the Infinity Gems.

Comment: This gauntlet has been revealed to be a fake